# interactivePopGestureRecognizer some time freez view touch and it will also cause [viewcontroller hash]: message sent to deallocated instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, dealloc, interactivepopgesture

I have added 'interactivePopGestureRecognizer' in some viewcontroller, also give back button on topbar . When user use Pop Gesture and push/pop view at that time it will freez top navigation controller view . After some time it will crash with  "[viewcontroller hash]: message sent to deallocated instance."

METHOD

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
         [super viewDidAppear:animated];

            //Pop GESTURE
            if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
                self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = true;
                self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    }
    -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        //Remove Pop Gesture
        if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = false;
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
        }
    }

DELEGATE METHOD
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // add whatever logic you would otherwise have

    return YES;
}
```

I have TabBar type application.

Answer (score 0):

The crash would be explained by you somehow failing to execute

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
```

in `viewDidDisappear`. Can you confirm that your delegate is actually being removed by stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: In viewDidDisappear respondsToSelector not executed !! , When i put this code in viewWillDisappear it will executed but not navigated .

Comment: Maybe try doing it in viewWillDisappear

Comment: viewWillDisappear navigation not work !! it will freez the viewcotroller.